# Positioning next/prev buttons along side of owl carousel in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am trying to position some text buttons either side of the owl carousel in bootstrap 3, vertically centered, and invisible when not viewed on a desktop.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">       
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right visible-desktop">
            <<<
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="owlCarousel" class="owl-carousel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left visible-desktop">
            >>>
        </div>
    </div>       
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <img id="savePlace" src="/assets/img/icon_paperclip_sm.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This puts the texts either side of the owl carousel but I cannot work out how to vertically center them, and they don't disappear when viewed on an iPhone. Is this possible?

Comment: is this you wanted?? http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1868/

Comment: No that interferes badly with the Bootstrap and Owl Carousel CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know height of the slider you can set it as `line-height` for button or button's container.

To hide buttons on smaller screens you can use `.hidden-sm .hidden-xs` classes and add `.col-xs-12 .col-md-8` for slider to fit full width of screen.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/matcygan/q70wbuwv/9/

Comment: The problem is I don't know the height. The .hidden-sm works though!